# Как оптимизировать проверку строки на символы из определенного алфавита?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, строки, оптимизация, валидация

Написал функцию, которая проверяет содержимое на символы из определенного алфавита:

```py
import re

def verification(text: str = None) -> bool:
    """Проверка на символы из алфавита <A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё ;>"""
    if text is None:
        return False
    pattern = r'[a-zA-ZА-Яа-яЁё]|[0-9]|[\s;]'
    return len(text) == len(''.join(re.findall(pattern, text)))
```

Но, у меня большие сомнения на ее оптимальность. Оптимальна ли она или можно было как-то по производительнее реализовать?

Comment: Если она не против, то да, можно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сделал как-то так, не вдаваясь в подробности регулярки:

```py
import re
from functools import lru_cache

pattern = re.compile(r'[a-zA-ZА-Яа-яЁё]|[0-9]|[\s;]')

@lru_cache(1000)
def verification(text: str = None) -> bool:
    """Проверка на символы из алфавита <A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё ;>"""
    if text is None:
        return False
    
    return len(text) == len(pattern.findall(text))
```

1. Компилируем заранее регулярку, так работает быстрее
2. Строку собирать не нужно, просто проверяем длину выхода `findall`
3. Кэшируем собственно функцию (размер кэша подобрать по вкусу, зависит от природы данных, нужен ли тут кэш и какой длины)

Как вариант ещё можно вместо регулярки собрать заранее множество всех допустимых символов, а в функции делать множество из входного текста и вычитать из него множество допустимых символов. Проверка пройдена, если в результате вычитания множеств получается пустое множество. По идее, это должно работать быстрее, чем регулярка, но нужно проверять.

Comment: Спасибо, сделал тест из 1000000 генераций случайных слов размером 25 символов. Ваш вариант работает быстрее на 1 секунду

Comment: @Алексей А в процентах это сколько? Для случайных слов лучше кэш вообще выключить, будет быстрее )